# ORA-01427 with table alias used in Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, subquery, ora-01427

I have the following snippet within a stored procedure:

(Note, this is not the original snippet, but exactly similar to it except that table and column names have been replaced with more generic ones for better understanding as well as to prevent giving out client code.)

```
UPDATE table_Orders c SET order_type = 
(
SELECT 'PE' FROM 
table_Orders A, 
table_Orders b, 
(SELECT DISTINCT order_id, cust_id, order_date FROM table_Orders WHERE shipment_type = 'T' AND order_availability = 'P' AND order_amt > 500 
AND cust_category = 'PREMIUM' ) d 
WHERE
A.order_id = d.order_id AND A.order_date = d.order_date AND A.cust_id= d.cust_id
AND A.order_id = b.order_id AND A.order_date = b.order_date AND A.cust_id= b.cust_id
AND A.shipment_type = b.shipment_type AND A.order_availability = b.order_availability AND A.product_id <> b.product_id
AND ((A.order_amt > 500 AND b.shipment_amt > 50) OR (A.shipment_amt > 50 AND b.order_amt > 500))
AND A.order_id = c.order_id AND A.order_date = c.order_date AND A.cust_id = c.cust_id 
AND A.shipment_type = c.shipment_type AND  A.order_availability = c.order_availability AND A.product_id = c.product_id 
);
COMMIT;
```

Now, my issue is that i am getting the error `ORA-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row` while executing the procedure. I tried putting the subquery at the end of the statement using an `IN` clause as below, but even that did not work:

```
UPDATE table_Orders c SET order_type =
(
SELECT 'PE' FROM 
table_Orders A, 
table_Orders b
WHERE
A.order_id = d.order_id AND A.order_date = d.order_date AND A.cust_id= d.cust_id
AND A.order_id = b.order_id AND A.order_date = b.order_date AND A.cust_id= b.cust_id
AND A.shipment_type = b.shipment_type AND A.order_availability = b.order_availability AND A.product_id <> b.product_id
AND ((A.order_amt > 500 AND b.shipment_amt > 50) OR (A.shipment_amt > 50 AND b.order_amt > 500))
AND A.order_id = c.order_id AND A.order_date = c.order_date AND A.cust_id = c.cust_id 
AND A.shipment_type = c.shipment_type AND  A.order_availability = c.order_availability AND A.product_id = c.product_id 
AND (A.order_id, A.cust_id, A.order_date) IN
(SELECT DISTINCT order_id, cust_id, order_date FROM table_Orders 
    WHERE shipment_type = 'T' AND order_availability = 'P' AND order_amt > 500 AND cust_category = 'PREMIUM')
);
COMMIT;
```

Could someone kindly guide me in the right direction, as to where I'm bungling this up, or how the subquery is already messed up ?

Code With JOIN --> This gives missing right parenthesis at c.product_Id just before the "JOIN" statement

```
UPDATE table_Orders c SET order_type =
(
 SELECT 'PE' FROM 
table_Orders A, 
table_Orders b
WHERE
A.order_id = d.order_id AND A.order_date = d.order_date AND A.cust_id= d.cust_id
AND A.order_id = b.order_id AND A.order_date = b.order_date AND A.cust_id= b.cust_id
AND A.shipment_type = b.shipment_type AND A.order_availability = b.order_availability AND A.product_id <> b.product_id
AND ((A.order_amt > 500 AND b.shipment_amt > 50) OR (A.shipment_amt > 50 AND b.order_amt > 500))
AND A.order_id = c.order_id AND A.order_date = c.order_date AND A.cust_id = c.cust_id 
AND A.shipment_type = c.shipment_type AND  A.order_availability = c.order_availability AND A.product_id = c.product_id 
JOIN
SELECT DISTINCT order_id, cust_id, order_date FROM table_Orders 
WHERE shipment_type = 'T' AND order_availability = 'P' AND order_amt > 500 AND cust_category = 'PREMIUM' d
ON A.order_id = d.order_id AND A.order_date = d.order_date AND A.cust_id= d.cust_id
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery is probably returning more than one row for some `c.order_id, c.order_date, c.cust_id, c.shipment_type, c.order_availability, c.product_id`

Without knowing your table structure and data it's hard for us to tell.

But you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE table_Orders c SET order_type = 'PE'
WHERE (c.order_id, c.order_date, c.cust_id, c.shipment_type, c.order_availability, c.product_id) IN 
(
SELECT A.order_id, A.order_date, A.cust_id, A.shipment_type, A.order_availability, A.product_id 
FROM 
table_Orders A, 
table_Orders b, 
(SELECT DISTINCT order_id, cust_id, order_date FROM table_Orders WHERE shipment_type = 'T' AND order_availability = 'P' AND order_amt > 500 
AND cust_category = 'PREMIUM' ) d 
WHERE
A.order_id = d.order_id AND A.order_date = d.order_date AND A.cust_id= d.cust_id
AND A.order_id = b.order_id AND A.order_date = b.order_date AND A.cust_id= b.cust_id
AND A.shipment_type = b.shipment_type AND A.order_availability = b.order_availability AND A.product_id <> b.product_id
AND ((A.order_amt > 500 AND b.shipment_amt > 50) OR (A.shipment_amt > 50 AND b.order_amt > 500))
);

COMMIT;
```

BTW, why don't you use the "JOIN Syntax" ?

---

**UPDATE** The same solution but with ANSI join syntax:

```
UPDATE table_Orders c 
   SET order_type = 'PE'
 WHERE (c.order_id, c.order_date, c.cust_id, c.shipment_type, c.order_availability, c.product_id) IN 
(
SELECT A.order_id, A.order_date, A.cust_id, A.shipment_type, A.order_availability, A.product_id 
FROM 
table_Orders A 
JOIN 
table_Orders b ON A.order_id = b.order_id AND A.order_date = b.order_date AND A.cust_id= b.cust_id AND A.shipment_type = b.shipment_type AND A.order_availability = b.order_availability AND A.product_id <> b.product_id 
JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT order_id, cust_id, order_date FROM table_Orders WHERE shipment_type = 'T' AND order_availability = 'P' AND order_amt > 500 
AND cust_category = 'PREMIUM' ) d ON A.order_id = d.order_id AND A.order_date = d.order_date AND A.cust_id= d.cust_id
WHERE ((A.order_amt > 500 AND b.shipment_amt > 50) OR (A.shipment_amt > 50 AND b.order_amt > 500))
);
```

Comment: hi @A.B.Cade , the subquery is indeed returning more than one row, 14 to be exact. That is why it has been stored in a table alias which has been used further. I tried out your solution, but the problem still persists. I also tried using join, but on that I'm getting a different error " Missing Right Parenthesis". I'll post the code as an edit.

Comment: Are you sure that my solution gave `ORA-01427`? because the way it works doesn't really care how many rows are returned from the subquery... see [this demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ab09/3)

Comment: Yes, I am sure. BTW, could you kindly check out the snippet above with the join clause and point out the issue in that one ?

Comment: That's not what I meant in "JOIN Syntax"... I meant tha ANSI way - not to use a comma between the tables you join (a,b and subquery d) but the `JOIN` key word. See [this](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2618)

Comment: Hey, I realized my problematic subquery was the entire set order_type= (...query...), and not the subquery using d as table alias. The ANSI join syntax helped a lot. Thanx.